# What can I do to challenge myself with React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

This is not classical question, like help me to solve task. Even vise versa. I was working with react for quite a while and found out that i think that I know it from each possible angle of view.

But I still have concerns about my level. I want to ask folks here to post me complicated questions that might get me stuck and will really appreciate any complexities that you will remember that seem to you difficult/tricky/etc...

Please don't ask about Redux, that one is still in progress.

Thanks in advance

I read through all docs and lots of articles, i can't find any unknown part.

Answer (score 1):

After you've completed learning `Redux` and assuming you already know some backend technology (Even if you don't, you can still challenge yourself for just the UI part). You can try cloning some app you find to have complex logic or a challenging UI.

For starters, people usually do `Netflix` or `YouTube`. You can give cloning `Notion` or `Evernote` a shot, if you plan on full stack build.

For UI only, there are tons of good, complex designs on `Dribble` and multiple articles on the web. [Here](https://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/examples-ui-design-7133429) is one article with some designs I really liked.

Or if you really want to test yourself out there, participate in hackathons. You can [find them](https://medium.com/@jonathanallengrant/the-7-best-websites-to-find-a-hackathon-the-hacklife-guide-3e420f2a565b) on [Devfolio](https://devfolio.co/hackathons), [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/hackathon/), [Devpost](https://devpost.com/hackathons).